# How can make my GoLand to detect dependency packages under $GOPATH/pkg/mod?

Tags: go, goland

I'm trying through kubebuilder tutorial, and just imported existing project to GoLand.

Workthrough with kubebuilder auto-generated scaffold codes, and auto-downloaded pkgs with go mod for me. I had no problem when I was working with commandline environment, but turns out, after opening the project with GoLand, IDE is failing to resolve imported package names, which means it is failing to detect - or link - packages installed by go mod.

I enabled go mod(with vendoring) and dep both from IDE preferences, set GOPATH and Go runtime properly, but the error keeps to appear.

I don't know why I'm getting this error, and how to solve it.

+) Working Directory is $GOPATH/src/example, all the logics and settings are placed in the directory. Installed dependencies are placed under $GOPATH/pkg/mod.

Comment: "set GOPATH and GOROOT" at least setting GOROOT is wrong. Probably you should decide whether to use a module build, a GOPATH build (or dep, No, you shoudn't).

Comment: @Volker the answer you provided is incorrect. You must set the path to the Go installation, or what's known as GOROOT, in GoLand for it to be able to use Go. This is part of the setup described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/quick-start-guide-goland.html

Comment: Volker talks about `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` _environment variables_. You talk about IDE settings called the same. But they are not the same thing (but might serve the same purpose).

Comment: I think my description was not appropriate. I was talking of IDE Runtime selection as GOROOT. That should not be a problem. I will update the question. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 6):

> I enabled go mod(with vendoring) and dep both from IDE preferences, set GOPATH and GOROOT properly, but the error keeps to appear.

Let's assume that you have the following setup on your machine:

- Go is installed under `/usr/lib/go`
- GOPATH is set to `/home/florin/go`
- the KubeBuilder project named `demobuilder` is created under `/home/florin/projects/demobuilder`. I recommend this as opposed to using GOPATH, as you do, for Go Modules projects because they behave in a different way while in GOPATH.

First, make sure that you have GoLand 2019.3.1 or newer.

Then, after creating the `demobuilder` project, start GoLand, then click on the `Open Project` button.

When the project is opened, if you have not configured yet, the IDE will ask you for the Go SDK configuration, aka GOROOT. It will be a yellow bar at the top of the editor. Click on the link on the right side to configure it. You can select the local installation and point it to `/usr/local/go`. If you don't have Go installed, you can also download it in a directory of your choice.

Then, the IDE should automatically notice that the project is a Go Modules based project and enable the support for them. If it's not, then go to `Settings/Preferences | Go | Go Modules` and enable that. *DO NOT* enable both Go Modules and *dep* support at the same time. If you did that, disable the dep integration and try again.

You can see all of these in [the help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/quick-start-guide-goland.html#open-project).

Comment: Enabling dep and go mod both at the same time was the problem. Never thought about that. Really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Is Go modules integration enabled via File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Go | Go Modules